# Changes done through the Experience Editor are not visible in the Sitecore Solution

Tags: experience-editor

I'm getting started with Sitecore and there is something i don't understand. I know how to add a specific rendering and placeholder to a template in the standard values window but when i do it through the experience editor, nothing is automatically updated in my Sitecore solution when i save my changes.

I expected for instance to see a new line in my template/standard values/Renderings and Placeholders.
Thank you for your help

Comment: If you are editing a content item and don't have that syncing with your solution that is why no changes are showing up. Check what item you are editing and make sure there is a serialized file related to that in your solution.

Comment: Could you add the steps you follow and the item/field and field you are expecting to be updated? It could be that you are editing the item, not the template? It's not clear to me if you expect something in Visual studio or Sitecore.

Comment: By "Solution" do you mean Visual Studio? If so, you need to make sure you have TDS installed and connected. Then you can sync changes, or make changes in Sitecore Rocks. That will automatically update VS if you have the rocks connector installed.

Comment: To follow up on @ChrisAuer's point here is a link that shows how to set that up: https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Blog/tds-how-to-install-tds-connector-rocks-2-0

Comment: Good question! not sure why this is marked as offtopic. You are confused as a beginner between templates and content. When you change a content through experience editor, templates are not changed. Hence you wont see that change happening in visual studio files. In most cases templates are serialized and kept in Visual studio. content is not serialized. But if content is serialized then you will see those changed in visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sitecore version 8.2 update 3 this is a known issue.

When you look in your Sitecore desktop.

- Select from the menu in the bottom right, the master database.
- Now go into the content editor and check to see if the data is there vs the web database.

Solution:

If after a publish the information is still not correct, you can delete the items in the web database, and publish again. Now it should be published correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a solution to the original question, as none of the comments on the question have been answered, so it's still unclear what the problem is.

Comment: this is not the answer to the question. web database/publish is out of topic here